# Google+ Api - get associated account in android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I'm using the new Google+ Sign-in api.  Once a user clicks sign in they can choose which google account to use, and then proceed to authorize the app.  How can I get the account which they picked?

Reason being is I have been using regular google auth for my app and the users account is tied to the email address.  With this Google+, I'm not sure how to get the account email without asking the user to selected the account again.

Comment: Please post some code otherwise we have nothing to start from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the user's profile information by using the [`PlusClient.loadPerson()` method](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_profile_information), which can include their email address if they choose to make it public. To [reliably get their email address](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address), you would use either the `PlusClient.getAccountName()` or use the `userinfo` REST endpoint after requesting the `userinfo.email` scope.

The code examples in the documentation walk through each of the above cases.

Comment: PlusClient.getAccountName() was what I needed.  Thanks.